# How to autorun a command in tab and how to open multiple tabs in split screen in Conemu?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, conemu, windows-8-x64

My OS is windows 8.1 (64bit) and ConEmu version is 131225.

This is my task group and it opens 3 tabs on startup as I want.

[image]

```
>""E:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"

>E:\redis-2.4.5-win32-win64\64bit\redis-server.exe

>""E:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i" rails s
```

- But In last tab I also wants to run a command "rails s" just after
  tab opens
- And I also want to see all console in single screen like this (on
  startup)

[image]

Comment: And what is in your "Startup" page? Have you selected your task? Running in a grid example exists here and in Wiki. As about bash and rails - consult to its man, I'm not a guru.

Comment: @Maximus yes I have selected task that's why I wrote "This is my task group and it opens 3 tabs on startup as I want."

Comment: @Maximus here is my startup page http://i.imgur.com/701eQzq.jpg

Comment: So, you have no problem with "script not allowed here"? Splits examples http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole#Example_6_(Split_Screen)

Comment: @Maximus- Thanks. Split window problem solved. Now can you help me how to run a command after tab opens?

After this tab open '"E:\RailsInstaller\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i' I want run this command 'rails s'

Comment: another example is once tab opens 'git status' should run. Is it possible?

Comment: @Maximus - I tried many variations from this but nothing worked https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Command_Line

Comment: Look, I believe, this is not a question for ConEmu, but for you shell (bash, yeah?). Search for the way to run command after shell start. Even simple cmd can do that: `cmd /k "your command here"`. And praised bash can't? Hard to believe...